# Accessing PHP api with the help of Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, security

I am making a mobile app and web part for the same. I have used php5 in mobile app to make all the api that are returning json data. 
Now I want to use the same api files, that are hosted on another server, using jquery so that I can pass the parameters to api file in data of jquery and then get the json data in response. But I am unable to understand that using jquery will it be safe to use everything on  client side ? Like creating sessions and send json data returned by one api to another page using jquery. I have been searching for a while on internet and I get some solutions that I should use curl in php and then returns the data from php that will call mobile app php and then return the data to jquery like in this manner :

Jquery -> web php file -> mobile-php-api(will return json data to web php file) -> jquery

Can anyone give valuable suggestions for it ? What should I use to parse already made api files with full authentication on web also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely understand which bit your asking about specifically but here goes...

What you appear to be describing is creating a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API in PHP, and a frontend in javascript/HTML.

For simple apps [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) may do but for larger frontend apps you might want to consider a MVC style client-side framework like [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org)

Finally, if by another page you mean another domain, your issues will either revolve around hosting (or possibly proxying) your api through the same domain as your frontend or using [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) (Cross Origin Resources Sharing) to work across domains. CORS support in internet explorer is bad and CORS authentication is tricky at best. You might want to consider [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) if you decide to stick with CORS.

Comment: Thanks! It would be really helpful. Can you tell me what would be best to use between BackboneJS and httpClient ?

Comment: If it was me I would probably code up some sort of thin client in PHP that essentially just maps or forwards API requests and handles some authentication in the process. I'd probably use the [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) to build it

Answer (score 3):

If your API isn't in the same domain of your application, using AJAX isn't a very effective solution, because of cross-domain requests. Some proxies and browsers block by default those requests.
I think you should use cURL, like you said. Or create a real WebService with SOAP, but it could be difficult if you need quickly your app.

To secure a communication between your PHP hosted on your first domain and your API, you can send a unique token generated with some challenge mechanisms. And hide this challenge in your PHP scripts (so your clients could not see it)